# How do I select one value from a table which was imported from Excel into Python with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to select just one value from a table which was imported into Python using Pandas.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel (r'x,y points.xlsx')
print (data)
```

Output:

```
    x   y
0   8  12
1   9  10
2  11  11
3  11  12
4  13  14
5  14  16
6  18  21
7  15  17
```

How do I select just one of the values.. For example the '18' in the 'x' field?

Comment: ``df.loc[6, 'x']`` Have a lok at the [indexing docs](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjZy_3_o8zuAhXGzTgGHd34DpEQFjAAegQIBxAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpandas.pydata.org%2Fpandas-docs%2Fstable%2Fuser_guide%2Findexing.html&usg=AOvVaw2OfH-11UL4gkrQpT-eHvAg)

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.  Introductory syntax is something you look up; it's not a Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `loc` (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) It takes the index of the selection and then the column, for example the value 18 is in the index `6` and column `x` so it will be

```
value = data.loc[6, "x"]
```

Answer (score 0):

To select and slice:

```
data[data.x == 18]
```

select slice and get only value from x column

```
data[data.x == 18].x
```